# IP for Gmail's smtp host

Tags: java, gmail, ip, jakarta-mail

Can anyone of you share the IPs that takes care gmail's SMTP host connectivity.
I'm aware Google has lot of IPs for GMAIL connectivity.
Any two or three would be of great help to me.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: `smtp.gmail.com`? I found this by googling the text of your question...

Answer (score 0):

```
POP address is: pop.gmail.com (XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX) port number 995
SMTP address is: smtp.gmail.com (XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX) port number 465
```

and

```
telnet smtp.gmail.com 25 // works
telnet smtp.gmail.com 465 // doesn't work
```